# An unknown pest or animal is heavily attacking my blueberries, what should I do?

Tags: pests, blueberries, berries

Something is attacking a lot of the leaves on my new superior blueberry bush, and I have a few fruit flies around it, what should I do to save it before it gets destroyed?[image: plant damage]

Comment: Do you have any pictures of the things that are attacking you plant? Close-ups of the insects, affected leaves, and bush as a whole would be great! There may be people here who already know the answer to your problem, but pictures would help those of us who don't, like me, as well as future passers-by. Thanks!

Comment: no, I can't tell what they are exactly, which is why I put "caterpillar" in quotes.

Comment: You need a camera instead of using a laptop!

Comment: I do have a camera. I use the one on my laptop.

Comment: And the shadow from your laptop in your picture above means we can't see anything!

Comment: i had to zoom in, but if you look carefully, and adjust the lighting you can see what it's showing.

Comment: Try standing on a different side of the plant when you take a picture so you're not in between the plant and the sun. Take it at the highest resolution you can and crop it down to the detail you want to show.